# CSS lines are repeating using stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I'm trying to order my stylesheets in a rails3 app, but I've got an issue with the lines repeating themselves using the *stylesheet_link_tag* helper.

In app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    :reset, :application, :event_calendar, :cache => false %>
```

In produced source code:

```
<link href="/assets/reset.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/event_calendar.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/reset.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/event_calendar.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Content of app/assets/stylesheets/ folder:

```
calendar (master *)$ ls app/assets/stylesheets/
application.css     event_calendar.css  reset.css
```

The same kind of problem appears using *javascript_include_tag* helper, I think both can be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the asset pipeline you only need include `application.css` as inside that there should be lines like...

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree . 
*/
```

Don't be fooled by the fact its commented out, this will be processed and will automatically include all the files in the same directory because of the `require_tree .` command.

Just put...

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, :cache => false %>
```

You can specify the order within `application.css` if you need your `reset.css` to come first

```
*= require reset
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```